# Send exactly one ProducerRecord with KafkaProducer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

With what configuration is it possible to send just one ProducerRecord with a KafkaProducer in order not to send messages in batches?

Or it is not possible to send just one record with KafkaProducer?

(With Kafka Streams it is possible to process just one record and send it to a topic).

My current configuration is:

```
  Properties kafkaProps = new Properties();
  kafkaProps.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
  kafkaProps.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
  kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "1");
  kafkaProps.put("retries", 3);
  kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, 120000);
  kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 1024);
  kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 0);
  kafkaProps.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 1024);
  kafkaProps.put("compression.type", "gzip");
  KafkaProducer producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(kafkaProps);
```

Comment: Is there any specific reason for not wanting to batch? You could simply set BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG to 0 and disable batching. See  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs

Comment: @AlexandreJuma The cluster on which I work has an old version of apache kafka streams with bugs and I want to simulate the one record processing of apache kafka streams with a kafkaproducer sending just one record to avoid those bugs!!

Comment: Well, you can try `BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG = 0` which will disable producer batching. Even so, I'm not entirely sure this will be enough to guarantee that your Kafka Streams Applications KStream consumer will consume one message at a time because the KStream internal consumer has a default max.poll.records of 1000 (at least in the latest versions) which can still make you face the same problems you have right now.

Comment: Kafka Streams is a *client side library*, not part of any cluster, so whatever bugs you have, aren't a problem with the cluster. Newer versions of Kafka Streams work with brokers down to at least 0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could explicitly `flush` the `producer` immediately after a `send`